Gemini is returning empty response for some queries in langchain using pinecone as vector storage
What I did: saved embeddings to pinecone, query using gemini.
Problem: sometimes I get an empty answer.
Initial guess: google safety settings blocking the response. I tried to disable safety settings as mentioned here: langchain docs. It did not fix the issue.
For example, response when it works properly (for some queries like):
{'input': 'what is art of war?', 'context': [Document(page_content='xi\ntied together in sheets and rolled up in scrolls. 11 Master Suns \nThe Art of War is certainly not a methodically organised, easily \nuseable, and applicable treatise on warfare. It is more like a series of gnomic utterances on the art of survival, and of interior and exterior methods of dealing with conflict and strategic decisions in general. By extension, it is a more generalised book of prover-bial wisdom, an ancient book of life. As for the author, he may not even have existed', metadata={'page': 11.0, 'source': '/content/art of war -Sant tuz.pdf'}), Document(page_content='xi\ntied together in sheets and rolled up in scrolls. 11 Master Suns \nThe Art of War  is certainly not a methodically organised, easily \nuseable and applicable treatise on warfare. It is more like a series of gnomic utterances on the art of survival, and of interior and exterior methods of dealing with conflict and strategic decisions in general. By extension, it is a more generalised book of prover-bial wisdom, an ancient book of life. As for the author, he may not even have existed', metadata={'page': 11.0, 'source': '/content/art of war -Sant tuz.pdf'}), Document(page_content='22\n11.   \n\n12.       \n    \n11. The art of war teaches us to rely not on the likelihood of \nthe enemys not coming, but on our own readiness to receive him\n23 not on the chance of his not attacking, but rather on the \nfacts that have made our position unassailable.24CHAPTER 8  VARIATION OF TACTICS', metadata={'page': 101.0, 'source': '/content/art of war -Sant tuz.pdf'})], 'answer': 'The Art of War is described as a series of gnomic utterances on the art of survival, and of interior and exterior methods of dealing with conflict and strategic decisions in general. It is also described as a more generalised book of proverbial wisdom, an ancient book of life. \n'}

This is a response while when getting "empty answer":
{'input': 'what are considerations while attack by fire?', 'context': [Document(page_content='58 CHINESE TEXT AND ENGLISH TRANSLATION\n5. In attacking with fire, one should be prepared to meet \nfive possible developments12\n6. 1 When fire breaks out inside the enemys camp, re-\nspond at once13 with an attack from without.\n7. \n8. \n9. \n7. 2 If there is an outbreak of fire, but the enemys soldiers \nremain quiet, bide your time and do not attack.14\n8. 3 When force of the flames has reached its height, follow it \nup with an attack, if that is practicable if not, stay where you are', metadata={'page': 126.0, 'source': '/content/art of war -Sant tuz.pdf'}), Document(page_content='58 CHINESE TEXT AND ENGLISH TRANSLATION\n5. In attacking with fire, one should be prepared to meet \nfive possible developments12\n6. 1 When fire breaks out inside the enemys camp, re-\nspond at once13 with an attack from without.\n7. \n8. \n9. \n7. 2 If there is an outbreak of fire, but the enemys soldiers \nremain quiet, bide your time and do not attack.14\n8. 3 When force of the flames has reached its height, follow it \nup with an attack, if that is practicable if not, stay where you are', metadata={'page': 126.0, 'source': '/content/art of war -Sant tuz.pdf'}), Document(page_content='15\n9. 4 If it is possible to make an assault with fire from with-\nout, do not wait for it to break out within, but deliver your attack at a favorable moment.\n16\n10. \n11. \n12.  \n10. 5 When you start a fire, be to windward of it. Do not \nattack from the leeward.17\n11. A wind that rises in the daytime lasts long, but a night \nbreeze soon falls.18\n12', metadata={'page': 126.0, 'source': '/content/art of war -Sant tuz.pdf'})], 'answer': ''}

The empty answer is reproducible for same query.
Here is the code I am using for inference:
from langchain.text_splitter import TokenTextSplitter
from langchain_pinecone import PineconeVectorStore
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains.combine_documents.stuff import create_stuff_documents_chain
from langchain.chains.retrieval import create_retrieval_chain

llm = ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(
    model= 'gemini-pro',# "gemini-1.5-flash",
    safety_settings={
        HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_UNSPECIFIED: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DEROGATORY: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_TOXICITY: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_VIOLENCE: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUAL: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_MEDICAL: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT: HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        
    },
)

# Initialize Pinecone vector store
index_name = 'pdf-index'
vectorstore = PineconeVectorStore(
    index_name=index_name,
    embedding=embeddings,
    pinecone_api_key=userdata.get('PINECONE_API_KEY'),
    namespace='art-of-war'
)

# Set up the retriever with custom search parameters
retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 3})

# Create the prompt template
template = """
You are a helpful AI assistant. Answer based on the context provided.
If the answer cannot be found in the context, say "I don't have enough information to answer that question."

Context: {context}
Question: {input}

Answer:
"""
prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(template)

# Create the retrieval chain
combine_docs_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm, prompt)
retrieval_chain = create_retrieval_chain(retriever, combine_docs_chain)

# Chat loop
while True:
    query = input("Ask a question about your PDF (or type 'quit' to exit): ")
    if query.lower() in ['quit', 'q']:
        break
    
    try:
        response = retrieval_chain.invoke({"input": query})
        print("\nResponse:", response)
        print("\nAnswer:", response["answer"])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"\nAn error occurred: {str(e)}")

Directly invoking LLM gives the response (no answer should be from langchain):
query = "what are considerations while attack by fire? context : [Document(page_content='58 CHINESE TEXT AND ENGLISH TRANSLATION\n5. In attacking with fire, one should be prepared to meet \nfive possible developments12\n6. 1 When fire breaks out inside the enemys camp, re-\nspond at once13 with an attack from without.\n7. \n8. \n9. \n7. 2 If there is an outbreak of fire, but the enemys soldiers \nremain quiet, bide your time and do not attack.14\n8. 3 When force of the flames has reached its height, follow it \nup with an attack, if that is practicable if not, stay where you are', metadata={'page': 126.0, 'source': '/content/art of war -Sant tuz.pdf'}), Document(page_content='58 CHINESE TEXT AND ENGLISH TRANSLATION\n5. In attacking with fire, one should be prepared to meet \nfive possible developments12\n6. 1 When fire breaks out inside the enemys camp, re-\nspond at once13 with an attack from without.\n7. \n8. \n9. \n7. 2 If there is an outbreak of fire, but the enemys soldiers \nremain quiet, bide your time and do not attack.14\n8. 3 When force of the flames has reached its height, follow it \nup with an attack, if that is practicable if not, stay where you are', metadata={'page': 126.0, 'source': '/content/art of war -Sant tuz.pdf'}), Document(page_content='15\n9. 4 If it is possible to make an assault with fire from with-\nout, do not wait for it to break out within, but deliver your attack at a favorable moment.\n16\n10. \n11. \n12.  \n10. 5 When you start a fire, be to windward of it. Do not \nattack from the leeward.17\n11. A wind that rises in the daytime lasts long, but a night \nbreeze soon falls.18\n12'"
llm.invoke(query).content

# Response:

 1. **When fire breaks out inside the enemy's camp, respond at once with an attack from without.** This is because the enemy will be disorganized and confused, and therefore more vulnerable to attack.
2. **If there is an outbreak of fire, but the enemy's soldiers remain quiet, bide your time and do not attack.** This is because the enemy may be preparing a trap, or they may be waiting for reinforcements.
3. **When the force of the flames has reached its height, follow it up with an attack, if that is practicable.** If it is not practicable, stay where you are. This is because the enemy will be more focused on fighting the fire than on defending themselves.
4. **If it is possible to make an assault with fire from without, do not wait for it to break out within, but deliver your attack at a favorable moment.** This is because the enemy will be less prepared for an attack from outside.
5. **When you start a fire, be to windward of it.** Do not attack from the leeward. This is because the wind will carry the fire towards the enemy, and it will be more difficult to put out.*emphasized text*

